# Display regular expression correct error messages

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a regular expression data annotation:

```
[StringLength(100)]
[Display(Description = "Password")]
[RegularExpression(@^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).+$)], ErrorMessage = " must include at least one upper case letter,one lower case letter and one numeric digit")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

How can I display an Error Message based on the reason the validation failed?

If the password is **12345678** then tell the user he didn't include at least 1 upper case and 1 lower case.

If the password is **abcdefgH** then the Error message will be:"must insert at least 1 digit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom class:

```
public class UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute()
        : base("**YOUR REGEX HERE**")
    {
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
[UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute, ErrorMessage = "ERRORMESSAGE"]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Add this to the global.asax to get recognized in client side:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(UpperAndLowerCaseAt‌​tribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way this could be done is to create your own regex validation attributes. You can extend the RegularExpressionAttribute and thereby seperate the different parts of your regex:

```
public class UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute()
        : base("**YOUR REGEX HERE**")
    {
    }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
[UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute, ErrorMessage = "ERRORMESSAGE"]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: It doesn't work in the view using unobtrusive validation, but i believe it should work for server side validation

Comment: My unobtrusive validation works except this one.
That doesn't work also after the submit.

Comment: I had to add in my global.asax this:
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(UpperAndLowerCaseAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));